# How to fill null values with mean

Tags: pandas, replace, nan

I have data:

```
print (df)
      Sex  Age  SbSp  Parch
0    male   22     1      0
1  female   38     1      0
2  female  NAN     0      0
```

There is some NAN value. I want to fill up with mean value.

I did use

```
df1 = df["Age"].fillna(value=df["Age"].mean()
```

But it did not affect my data set.

What is problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read first in the help center, how to ask a good question on this forum: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. So we can better unterstand your question and can help you with your problems.

Comment: Are you reading this from csv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is problem `NAN` are not `np.nan` values (missing), but strings `NAN`s. So need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) and then cast to `float`:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].replace({'NAN':np.nan}).astype(float)
df["Age"] = df["Age"].fillna(value=df["Age"].mean())
```

Another more general solution is convert non numeric to `NaNs` by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`:

```
df['Age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Age'], errors='coerce')
df["Age"] = df["Age"].fillna(value=df["Age"].mean())
print (df)
      Sex   Age  SbSp  Parch
0    male  22.0     1      0
1  female  38.0     1      0
2  female  30.0     0      0
```

If use read_csv add parameter `na_values` for convert `NAN`s to `np.nan`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, na_values='NAN')
```

Comment: If I do this I got this error                                                                  
          TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'str'

Comment: Sorry, I rewrite solution.